# GKR Protocol - is it one Sum-Check per layer or is it one Sum-Check per gate?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, snarks, interactive-proofs

I am reading about GKR protocol from Justin Thaler's book - [Proofs, Arguments & Zero Knowledge](https://people.cs.georgetown.edu/jthaler/ProofsArgsAndZK.pdf)

On Page 59,

> In the first message, $P$ tells $V$ the (claimed) output(s) of the circuit. The protocol then works its way in iterations towards the input layer, with **one iteration devoted to each layer**.

I am a little confused about what exactly iteration means here. Does one iteration means one sum-check proof or can each iteration (corresponding to a layer) contain multiple sum-check proofs?

Page 61, Lemma 4.7

$W_i(z) = \sum_{b,c \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^{k_{i+1}}} add_i (z,b,c)\cdot (W_{i+1}(b)+W_{i+1}(c)) + mult_i(z,b,c)\cdot (W_{i+1}(b)\cdot W_{i+1}(c))$

Consider this circuit from Page 65

[image]

For e.g. for the circuit above, in the first (topmost) layer, won't we have to run the sum-check protocol for both $W_0(0)=4$  & $W_0(1)=2$  separately? And in the next layer, we will need 4 sum-check protocol runs - $W_1(0,0)=1$, $W_1(0,1)=4$, $W_1(1,0)=2$  & $W_1(1,1)=1$. And so on?

I can think of making it just one sum-check per layer but that will work only if all the gates in that layer are addition gates.

If all the gates in a layer are addition gates, then we can change the sum-check equation to

$\sum_{z \in s} W_i(z) = \sum_{z \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^{log(s)}} \sum_{b,c \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^{k_{i+1}}} add_i (z,b,c)\cdot (W_{i+1}(b)+W_{i+1}(c)) + mult_i(z,b,c)\cdot (W_{i+1}(b)\cdot W_{i+1}(c))$

Where number of gates in that layer is $s$

But this will not work unless all gates in that layer are addition gates.

Comment: I surmise that each circuit layer requires one sum-check. The GKR protocol aims to compel the prover to demonstrate, via the sumcheck protocol, to the verifier that the computation of each layer is correct. This layer-by-layer proof approach can reduce the output of the circuit back to the input of the circuit.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to recall exactly the technical details of the GRK protocol, because it's so old...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

The GKR protocol consists of one execution of the sum-check sum protocol *per layer*.

**Long answer**

Considering that a layer has $2^{k}$ gates, the function
$W_i: \{0,1\}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$, defined as

$$W_i(z) = \sum_{b,c \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^{k}} 
add_i (z,b,c)\cdot (W_{i+1}(b)+W_{i+1}(c)) + mult_i(z,b,c)\cdot (W_{i+1}(b)\cdot W_{i+1}(c))$$

maps every gate $z$ of the $i$-th layer to its output value.
You should verify and convince yourself about this before continuing the analysis (basically, for each gate $z$, there will be a single pair $(a, b)$, corresponding to the left and right input wires of $z$, thus, only one instance of $add(z, a, b)$ or of $mult(z, a, b)$ will be equal to 1 in the summations in $W$).

Now, what the GKR protocol does is to define a low-degree polynomial extension $\tilde{W}:\mathbb{F}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ of $W_i$
and it applies the sum-check sum protocol on $\tilde{W}$ running over the variables $a$ and $b$, not on $z$ (so there are not 3 summations as you wrote!).

In other words, for some function $f$, we can write
$$\tilde{W}(z) = \sum_{a, b \in \{0, 1\}^k} f(z, a, b)$$
And when given a polynomial $G$ claimed to be equal to $\tilde{W}$, we can pick a random field element $r^\star$ and check if $G(r^\star) = \tilde{W}(r^\star)$.
By the Schwartz-Zippel lemma, if this equality is true, then we can assume $G$ and $\tilde{W}$ are indeed equal.
However the verifier can only compute $y = G(r^\star)$, but not $\tilde{W}(r^\star)$, since they don't know $\tilde{W}$ (only the prover does).

So, they both run the sum-check protocol (running on all the $2^{k+1}$ possible values for the pairs $(a, b)$) to verify that
$$y = \sum_{a, b \in \{0, 1\}^k} f(r^\star, a, b)$$

Notice that if the sum-check sum protocol has a positive answer, we conclude that
$y = \sum_{a, b \in \{0, 1\}^k} f(r^\star, a, b)$,
thus,
$G(r^\star) = \tilde{W}(r^\star)$,
thus,
$G = \tilde{W}$,
thus,
all gates of the $i$-th layer were evaluated correctly.

(There is a detail here: at the end of the protocol, the verifier cannot finish the sum-check sum protocol, since this requires evaluating
$f(r^\star, a^\star, b^\star)$ for random $r^\star, a^\star, b^\star$.
This check is then "shifted" to the next layer and the GKR protocol continues recursively).

Comment: I understood the answer but have a question. Here in this video by the author of the protocol - https://youtu.be/x8pUxFptfb0?si=6Kimv058B3k9bHyK&t=879 - I have linked to the time where she says that for multiplication gates, she has to do 2 sum-checks

Comment: She again repeats this here at this timestamp - https://youtu.be/x8pUxFptfb0?si=CWjeREbO82wdQ8H1&t=998

Comment: Your question was about executing the sum-check protocol one or multiple times per layer. As I said in the answer, you just need one. It seems that she is talking about how you go from layer i to layer i+1 in the recursive step of GKR. If so, this is covered in Thaler's book and, basically, for the next layer you again just need the sum-check protocol one time because of the 2-to-1 trick. But she might also be talking about something else or about a specific application of the GKR protocol. I didn't have time to watch the full video.

Comment: `Your question was about executing the sum-check protocol one or multiple times per layer.` That's what she is also talking about - she is saying it's just once per layer for addition but you have to use the 2-to-1 trick to make it just once for multiplication gates. Which isn't clear.

Comment: Also - where is the `2-to-1` trick for multiplication explained in Thaler's book? I can only find the technique where they restrict the MLE to a line & thus verify W(a) & W(b) using just one point instead of two, but that isn't specific to multiplication like she says

Comment: @user93353 As I said, I didn't have time to check the video, so I don't know what she is talking about. When I heard "2-to-1 trick" I thought it was the technique to collapse the verification of $W(r')$ and $W(r'')$ into a single verification (and maybe it is). But anyway I've answered your question. If there is something you don't understand in my answer, I will be glad to clarify it.

Comment: Btw, consider this: sum-check protocol has verification cost > log|C| . If it was applied to every gate, GKR's verification cost would be |C| log |C|, which is heavier than running the circuit locally, so, it would be pointless.

Comment: I agree it's run only once per layer. But I was wondering why the author of the paper thinks this trick is required for mult gates

Comment: I have opened a separate question for this - https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/110936/what-is-the-pcp-2-to-1-trick-why-is-it-needed-not-needed-in-the-gkr-protocol